# SQ186: Over 100 keys in distinct

Tags: spring, jena, virtuoso

I made a java application with apache jena framework that allows to retrieve data from Virtuoso via SPARQL request.
When I do my SPARQL request I got the following error :

`SQ186: Over 100 keys in distinct`

The number of different properties interrogated from Virtuoso is over than 100. So that's why i get this error. 
it's the Sparql request :

```
PREFIX  ns:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  tk:   <http://www.trooclick.com/ontologies/2013/10/tk.owl#>
 ....
 SELECT DISTINCT  ?s0 ?s0_type ?s0_acquirer_companyName_normalized ....................
  WHERE
  {
    ?s0 ns:type ?s0_type .
    ?s0 tk:acquirer ?s0_acquirer .
    ?s0_acquirer tk:companyName ?s0_acquirer_companyName .
    OPTIONAL
      { ?s0 tk:deal ?s0_deal
        OPTIONAL
          { ?s0_deal tk:valueDeal ?s0_deal_valueDeal
           ................
         }
      }
   FILTER regex(?s0_type, tk:Acquisition, "i")
}
```

In fact the method that throws the exception is *execSelect()*. I called this method when i execute the request on the graph

```
 VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, graph);
 ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
```

Here is execSelect() method

```
    public ResultSet execSelect() {
        ResultSet ret = null;
        try {
            stmt = graph.createStatement();         
            stmt.setFetchSize(1000);    
            java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getQueryString());

            return new VResultSet(graph, rs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JenaException("Can not create ResultSet.:" + e);
        }
    }
```

so i've set stmt.setFetchSize(1000); but nothing changed i've always the same error

I use ubuntu 14.04 and virtuoso version is 7

Thank you 
Nihat

Comment: What's the purpose of `ResultSet ret = null;`, since  `ret` is never used?  This isn't a minimal example.  Nor is it complete;  there's not enough here to reproduce the problem.  In the question you write about execSelect, but you're not calling execSelect, you're calling executeQuery, and getting a java.sql.ResultSet back, which is not a com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet.

Comment: That said, you can see the error message in [line 169 of sqlhash.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/virtuoso-opensource/ci/74f8bf4fbb92ed60f52ba6d10febb792b896a0b0/tree/libsrc/Wi/sqlhash.c#l169).  I'd guess you're doing something like `select distinct * ...` with more than 100 variables.  I guess the answer is to use fewer variables.

Comment: For future reference..  Questions specifically regarding [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by editing the source code and recompiling.
It is therefore necessary to increase the value of just this constant `SETP_DISTINCT_MAX_KEYS` which is located in the `sqlnode.h` file (path: `libsrc / Wi / sqlnode.h`)

Comment: Worth noting that this solution was found through a post to the the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support)...